# How can I transfer parameters from function to function within one Controller in Symfony 4?

Tags: php, controller, twig, symfony4

I am trying to pass a parameter from a FORM to a twig, that is different from the one where I make my data input. If this explanation is messy - here's more simplified version... I have just started to study php+symfony so please don't hurt me too hard...

I have two empty fields on a "CREATE" page,
I fill them with say AAA and BBB each,
I want AAA and BBB to appear on another "FORMZ" page.

I am NOT using any database, so no need to use ObjectManager etc, it's only to understand how everything's working...

I have created a ArticleFormType.php file

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder

        ->add('title', TextType::class, [
            'attr' =>   [
                'placeholder' => "title from ArticleFormType",
                'class' => 'form-control'
                        ]
        ])
        ->add('content')

        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, [
            'label' => 'SAVE'
        ])
    ;
}


public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => MyClassArticle::class,
    ]);
}
```

and that is my Controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/formz", name="formz")
 */
public function index()
{


    $title = 'Created by DT';


    return $this->render('formz/index.html.twig', [
       'title' => $title
    ]);
}

/**
 * @Route("/formz/create", name="create")
 */
public function create (Request $request, ObjectManager $manager ) {


        $article = new MyClassArticle();
        $task = new ArticleFormType();

        $form = $this->createForm(ArticleFormType::class, $article, [
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('create'),
        ]);





        $form->handleRequest($request);

    dump($article);

    if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            dump($article);


            return $this->redirectToRoute('formz');


    }



    return $this->render('formz/create.html.twig', [
        'formTest' => $form->createView()
    ]);

}
```

I don't get how can I transfer my $article to a public function index() - I heard it can be done somehow (in the case above) by passing parameters from public function create() to public function index().
Can anybody help me with that please?

I am thanking you in advance!

Comment: Store your data somewhere and then retrieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect to page with parameters in symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499806/redirect-to-page-with-parameters-in-symfony)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496975/symfony-redirect-with-2-parameters

Answer (score 0):

you need to store the article somewhere, ideally through doctrine (entity save)

then you need to update your index route to be something like this

```
@Route("/formz/{article}", name="formz")
function index(Artile $article = null)
```

Then you can use the following with redirectToRoute

```
$this->redirectToRoute("formz", array("article" => $article))
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! The problem is that I don't know how to strore the article... it's been only couple of days since I started learning symfony... can you please explain? Thank you.

Comment: your best bet is to read this: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html the symfony docs are amazing and will answer pretty much everything you want to know. it'll be quicker for you to digest this than me explaining.

Comment: Thank you! The small issue is that I am not using any database for the moment. My class  has no @Route or whatever... Well, I suppose I am wrong but the problem is that FOR ME it looks like I am not supposed to use any Doctrine for the moment... But ok, I'll do my best to understand...

Comment: then you wont be able to do what you want as how will you be able to pass the data? you could, i guess, have the article stored in a session and then get that from the session. but that seems somewhat convoluted

Comment: Hi Andy, so that was a solution:        return $this->index($article); in controller and just a public function index($article) in  a Controller... Then I just         return $this->render('formz/index.html.twig', [
          'article' => [$article]
        ]);                   and this seems to work after all...  (And thanks for your kind reply - it gave me some clues!)